# QAction with custom parameter

Tags: c++, qt

I want to execute my slot with parameter when dynamically created QAction clicked, but I can't add my variables when creating QAction in QMenu, and default `triggered()` slot can't pass it.

To be more clear, I want to archieve something like this:

```
connect(someAction, SIGNAL( triggered(MyClass*) ), this, SLOT( execute(MyClass*) );
```

How I can get this? I tried to create custom QAction, but I don't know how to add it to QMenu - there is no function like `addAction(QAction)`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass? It sounds like you try to pass on something in a way that is not recommended. Try to find alternative concepts like a singleton instance.

Comment: Probably, QActionGroup is what you need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can store your parameter in the action itself as a `QVariant` using `QAction::setData()` function. For example:

```
QVariant v = qVariantFromValue((void *) yourClassObjPointer);
action->setData(v);
```

In the slot you will have to extract the pointer like:

```
void execute()
{
    QAction *act = qobject_cast<QAction *>(sender());
    QVariant v = act->data();
    YourClass yourPointer = (YourClass *) v.value<void *>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Gather your dynamic `QAction`'s in one `QActionGroup` using `QAction::setActionGroup()`
2. Use `QAction::setData()` to store the custom data in each `QAction`.
3. `connect` `QActionData`'s signal `triggered(QAction*)` to some `slot`.